# Django custom admin actions with an intermediate page submit not triggered

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-admin-filters, django-admin-actions

Writing an admin action so an administrator can select a template they can use to send a message to subscribers by inputting only the subject and text message. Using a filtered list from the admin panel an action called `broadcast` is triggered on this queryset (the default filter list). The admin action 'broadcast' is a function of a sub-classed UserAdmin class. The intermediate page is displayed that shows a dropdown selector for the `emailtype`, the queryset items (which will be email addresses, input fields for the subject and message text (message is required field) a button for optional file attachment followed by send or cancel buttons. Problem 1) after hitting the send button the app reverts to the admin change list page. In the broadcast function, the conditional `if 'send' in request.POST:` is never called.

**`forms.py`**

```py
mail_types=(('1','Newsletter Link'),('2','Update Alert'))

class SendEmailForm(forms.Form):
    _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
    #Initialized 'accounts' from Account:admin.py Actions: 'send_email' using>> form = SendEmailForm(initial={'accounts': queryset})
    my_mail_type=forms.ChoiceField(label='Mail Type',choices=mail_types,required=False)
    subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': ('Subject')}),required=False)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': ('Teaser')}),required=True,min_length=5,max_length=1000)
    attachment = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(),required=False)
    accounts = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="To:",
                                           queryset=Account.objects.all(),
                                           widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'placeholder': ('user_email@somewhere.com')}),
                                           empty_label='user_email@somewhere.com',
                                           required=False,
```

**`admin.py`**

```py
from .forms import SendEmailForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def broadcast(self, request, queryset):
         form=None      
       if 'send' in request.POST:
                print('DEBUGGING: send found in post request')
                form = SendEmailForm(request.POST, request.FILES,initial={'accounts': queryset,})
                if form.is_valid():
                    #do email sending stuff here
                    print('DEBUGGING form.valid ====>>> BROADCASTING TO:',queryset)
                    #num_sent=send_mail('test subject2', 'test message2','From Team',['dummy@hotmail.com'],fail_silently=False, html_message='email_simple_nb_template.html',)
                    self.message_user(request, "Broadcasting of %s messages has been started" % len(queryset))
                    print('DEBUGGING: returning to success page')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request, 'success.html', {})
        if not form:    
            # intermediate page right here 
            print('DEBUGGING: broadcast ELSE called')
            form = SendEmailForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial={'accounts': queryset,})
        return TemplateResponse(request, "send_email.html",context={'accounts': queryset, 'form': form},)
```

**`send_email.html`**

```html
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""  >
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <div>   
        <div>
            
            <p>{{ form.my_mail_type.label_tag }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.my_mail_type }}</p>
        </div>
        <div>        
           <p>{{ form.accounts.label_tag }}</p>
            <p>
                {% for account in form.accounts.queryset %} 
                    {{ account.email }}{% if not forloop.last %},&nbsp;{% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </p>
            <p><select name="accounts" multiple style="display: form.accounts.email">
                {% for account in form.accounts.initial %}  
                    <option value="{{ account.email }}" selected>{{ account }}</option>

                {% endfor %}
            </p></select>
        </div>
        <div>
            
            <p>{{ form.subject.label_tag }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.subject }}</p>
        </div>
        <div>

            <p>{{ form.message.label_tag }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.message }}</p>
        </div>  
        <div>
            
            <p>{{ form.attachment.label_tag }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.attachment.errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.attachment }}</p>
        </div> 
    
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_email" />
                <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="{% trans 'Send messages' %}"/> 
                <a href="{% url 'admin:account_account_changelist' %}" name="cancel" class="button cancel-link">{% trans "Cancel this Message" %}</a>
       

    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Inspecting the browser at the *POST* call seems to show all the data was bound. Another poster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591215/django-admin-form-action-dont-send-post-params) suggested the admin action buttons divert requests to an internal 'view' and you should redirect to a new view to handle the *POST* request. I can't get that to work because I can't get a redirect to 'forward' the queryset. The form used in the suggested fix was simpler and did not use the queryset the same way. I have tried writing some FBVs in Forms.py and Views.py and also tried CBVs in views.py but had issues having a required field (message) causing non-field errors and resulting in an invalid form. I tried overriding these by writing `def \_clean_form(self):` that would ignore this error, which did what it was told to do but resulted in the form essentially being bound and validated without any inputs so the intermediate page didn't appear. Which means the rabbit hole returned to the same place. The `send` button gets `ignored` in either case of FBVs or CBVs, which comes back to the admin action buttons Post requests revert to the admin channels!
Any ideas on how to work around this? Key requirements: From the admin changelist action buttons:

1. the Form on an intermediate page must appear with the queryset passed from the admin changelist filter.
2. The `message` input field on the form is a required field.
3. the send button on the HTML form view needs to trigger further action.

NOTES: My custom Admin User is a subclass of `AbstractBaseUser` called Account, where I chose not to have a username and am using `USERNAME_FIELD='email'`. Also, I do not need a `Model.py` for the `SendEmailForm` as I don't need to save the data or update the user models, just send the input message using the chosen template and queryset. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never work in your case:

1. You call the action.
2. You receive the Action Confirmation template render.
3. After pressing "SEND" in your "confirmation" step, you send a `POST` request to ModelAdmin, not in your FB-Action.
4. ModelAdmin gets a `POST` request without special parameters and shows you a `list_view` by default.

In your case, you should add a `send_email.html` template:

```
{% load l10n %}
{# any your staff here #}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{# any your staff here #}
    <div>
        
        <p>{{ form.attachment.label_tag }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.attachment.errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.attachment }}</p>
    </div> 

    {% for obj in accounts %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_selected_action" value="{{ obj.pk|unlocalize }}" />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="broadcast" />
{# any your staff here #}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

You should change your action view, some things are not working in your code:

```
def broadcast(self, request, queryset):
    form = SendEmailForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, initial={'accounts': queryset})

    if 'send' in request.POST:
        ...  # your staff here
            if form.is_valid():
                ...  # your staff here
                # return HttpResponseRedirect(request, 'success.html', {} )  this is NEVER WORK
                return TemplateResponse(request, 'success.html', {})
    ...  # your staff here
    return TemplateResponse(request, "send_email.html",context={'accounts': queryset, 'form': form},)
```

I am giving you a solution that I have **TESTED** on my project. I am sure, it works.

We were told on DjangoCon Europe 2022 that django-GCBV is like a ModelAdminAction and I've added a link below for the talk.

https://youtu.be/HJfPkbzcCJQ?t=1739

Comment: @MD Thanks for the suggestion, currently getting Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: Invalid filter: 'unlocalize'. Will try to debug this one.

Comment: you forget to load filter library {% load l10n %}

Comment: Thank you, I have now tried multiple version of your suggestion to add to the HTML template but they have had no effect on how the 'submit' button functions. It still reverts to the default changelistview. It appears either the form is invalid or when I override the non-field errors the the form is automatically bound and valid and the intermediate page does not appear but the post request goes straight to the success page.

Comment: Are you suggesting that slide 61-62 will solve this?if yes you can add here and show how. I worry that your patch to swap the order of how the arguments are passed will not enable the extra context i.e. the queryset and subject and message content to be passed. I dont think I need to return modelAdmin object that sent the post request but wont this create a thread waiting for a response?

Comment: i corrected my answer and give you a working solution, i tested it. Also on my video talk you can find a link to repository with examples, have you check it?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I dont appear to have much luck with this. After Selecting users from the changelistview and selecting the broadcast option from the actions dropdown menu, It correctly redirects to the send_email.html page (which shows no change from my version, as is correct). After filling in the subject and message fields and hitting the send button it reverts back to the changelistview (as my version did) but now displays the warning message 'No Action selected'.

Comment: I put a debugging print statements inside the 'if send...' and 'if form.isvalid...' and neither get triggered. I also tried changing my SendEmailForm to an ActionForm subclass but there is no difference to the result I get from your suggestion here. I get the same message. Any thoughts? Also I tried to look at your repository for further insights but the Django-admin repository is empty and there is no link on the youtube video.

Comment: Are you sure? You take my code from template? You have <input type="hidden" name="action" value="broadcast" /> in template? Please put view code and template code in your question.

Comment: @Mixim Danilov Update: now get no response from submit /send button Form is invalid<ul class="errorlist"><li>accounts<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
<bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <SendEmailForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(_selected_action;my_mail_type;subject;message;attachment;accounts)>>   Does your PrintSchemaForm have any required fields as per my requirement in my SendEmailForm message field?

Comment: ok, it means - it works.Right now you have a problem with the form, it is not valid. Can you print form.errors ?

Comment: Sorry your solution doesn't work. No progress to my solution. I stated in the initial description of the problem "a required field (message) causing non-field errors and resulting in an invalid form." I can override this but it still reverts back to the Changeviewlist without actioning  'Send' button. I suspect your suggestion works only on your Form without required fields? The form errors caused my your implementation are in my previous comment. Specifically yours causes "<li>accounts<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li>"

Comment: i don't know your account model, but, I think, problem is here:  <option value="{{ account.email }}" selected>{{ account }}</option>. Instead ID you send email. I am sure, my code is work for everywhere. If you think, it is not work in your case - i can not help you any more.

Comment: A bit if a bad hack but if I added this function to the SendEmaiForm objects it progresses to success page. Not ideal :( ` def _clean_form(self):
  try:
   cleaned_data = self.clean()
  except ValidationError as e:
   pass
  else:
   if cleaned_data is not None:
    self.cleaned_data = cleaned_data   
  try: 
   if 'message' in self.errors:
    self.errors.pop('message')
  except: pass
  try: 
   if 'accounts' in self.errors:
    self.errors.pop('accounts')
  except: pass`

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get that to work because I can't get a redirect to 'forward' the queryset

I have a similar use case and save the primary keys of the filtered query set in the session (in your case you may be able to save emails and avoid another query)

```
def broadcast(self, request, queryset):
    request.session["emails"] = list(queryset.values_list("emails", flat=True))
    return HttpResponseRedirect("url_to_new_view")
```

I can then use primary keys to filter query set in the new view. You also handle the form in this new view.

```
User.objects.filter(email__in=self.request.session["emails"])
```

Comment: Thank you I tried something similar with:  <br/> ```def braodcast(self,request,queryset):
  selected = request.POST.getlist(queryset)
  ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(queryset.model)
  return HttpResponseRedirect("/send_email/?ct=%s&ids=%s" % (ct.pk, ",".join(selected)))
``` <br/> the problem I had here was linking it to the urls.py in a way that passes the variable context in a url path.